# Bounded mapping between two Holder spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let  $T:C^{k,\beta}\to C^{k,\alpha}$ be a operator between two Holder spaces, $\alpha < \beta $ and
$u: \overline{\Omega} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is bounded domain.

I would like to proof that T is bounded operator.
I think is it enough to proof that $C^{k, \beta} \subset C^{k, \alpha}$ but i couldn't. Please help.

Comment: Hint: $|x-y|^\beta = |x-y|^\alpha \cdot |x-y|^{\beta -\alpha}$.

Comment: $||u||_{C^{k, \alpha} \leq ||u||_{C^{k, \beta} diam(\overline{\Omega})^{\alpha - beta}$

Answer (score 0):

The question is essentially answered in the comment by the OP:

$$\|u\|_{k, \alpha} \le C \| u\|_{k, \beta},$$

where

$$C =\max\left\{ 1,  \left(\text{diam}\overline\Omega\right)^{\beta -\alpha}\right\}$$

Comment: Why we take max and not only power of diam?